# Help identify the type of ML problem

Tags: machine-learning

I have 3 data files (no missing values, structured nicely such that each line is a record and each column is a feature/variable).
Each line describes a Person with a unique ID number (and each person has only one line in each file); e.g. (displaying two persons, IDs 217 & 456):

```
------  ID        Age  Flag
File#1: 217 … … … 26    0
        456 … … … 12    1
        321 … … … 44    0
        789 … … … 67    NA
            … … … 
File#2: 217 … … … 34    1
        456 … … … 23    0
        321 … … … 45    0
        789 … … … 76    NA
            … … … 
File#3: 217 … … … 31    0
        456 … … … 56    0
        321 … … … 39    1
        789 … … … 77    NA
            … … …
```

Where the first field is the **ID**, the next to last is the **Age** of the person, and the last one is **Flag**  (= 1 if the Age is correct; 0 if not) => [edit:] **NOTE:** *only about 10% of the records has this flag set* [someone verified the correct age], **the other 90% the Flag are missing (NA)**. The other features are all different (each file has its own distinct features not shared with the other, apart from the above 3 fields).
The variable if interest is **Age**; I need to devise an algorithm to decide which of the "Age" fields is the correct one (assume one is correct, and I know it from the files). This could be a probabilistic algorithm which assigns a probability to each of the age "candidates" and I'll pick the highest as winner. 
Can some one please point me in the right direction? *What type of problem is this?* (and maybe suggest which algorithm(s) can be used for this type of problem?).

Comment: Suppose you want to know that an age of 26 is correct or not, then I can see that directly from the data. Why do we need an algorithm, if I am not wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I wasn't clear in my question so hopefully fixed it now.